# How to use day of the week and the day of the month to get year in python?

Tags: python, date, datetime, time

for example how would you get "2016" from

Fri, Feb, 19 ?

I have a database from somewhere that has entries from the last 4 years but only lists dates as day of the week and day of the month, and I need to get the year from each. There should not be any repetitions because there is only four years of data, and date & day of the week alignments do not repeat in that timeframe.

Comment: You cant if there is no additional information. It's like me asking what year is May 14

Comment: even if you do some day of the week hack arounds, it might still be ambiguous

Comment: @Untitled123 If you know the day of the week and that it was in the last 4 years, you can work out the year

Comment: Is it never ambiguous? I'd imagine that while it might work for some 4 year ranges it wouldn't always

Comment: @Untitled123 don't imagine, work it out. For any date of the year, the day of the week only increase by at most 5 days in 4 years (that's if there's a leap year).

Comment: hm interesting that it only works for up to 4 year ranges, awfully lucky

Comment: @Untitled123: a brute-force test (exploiting that Gregorian calendar repeats itself every 400 years) shows that (weekday, month, day) is unique for 5 years span such as 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doomsday_rule

Comment: The person who created your db schema should be soundly thrashed.

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
import datetime

year = next(date for year in (2013, 2014, 2015, 2016)
            for date in (datetime.date(year, 2, 19),)
            if date.weekday() == 4).year
```

Comment: the answer is incomplete without the proof (or assertion in the code) that there is exactly one matching year for a valid input.

Answer (score 3):

This is just slightly different from @zondo's answer who beats me to it, but I'll put this up anyway because I prefer not to have the `.year` at the end of a long expression:

```
year = next(y for y in range(2013, 2017) if datetime.date(y, 2, 19).weekday() == 4)
```

Comment: I don't think `year` is an appropriate name in your case because you are assigning it to the whole date, not just the year.

Comment: @zondo It is the year (and that's one difference from your code). Try it. The output is 2016.

Comment: Oh, you're right.  I think I like yours more than mine.

Comment: Why this is better: Readability == More understandable and maintainable. Also doesn't require two `for` loops in expression.